# No +2 reputation for edit after 2K reputation

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

Recently, I got 2K reputations and I noticed I can review edits.

Another thing, I noticed is that, I was not getting +2 reputations for each successful(approved) edits in SO posts.

I made an edit to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6477255/1433665 but I didn't get any reputations for that.

Are users with 2K+ reputations not supposed to get reputations for successful edits?

Is there any specific reason for this behaviour in SO?

Comment: You only get rep for suggested edits. Once you have 2k, you're not making suggestions anymore, you edit directly.

Comment: The only way you get reputation is if someone else gives it to you. You get rep on a _suggested_ edit because 3 people approved it. When you can edit a post instantly, there is no one checking what you did, so no one can give you rep for your action.

Comment: Okay. Got it. :D

Comment: See [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for a list of when you gain/lose reputation.